# Knockoutjs computed won't recalculate after update

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, ko.observablearray, computed-observable

I'm working with an observable array of "Parts" that contains an observable of "Vol". I currently have the volume of each part as well as the total amount displayed. When the application starts the total amount is added correctly. However, when I change the volume of a part the total amount doesn't get recalculated.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li data-bind="foreach:  Parts">
        <input data-bind="value: Vol" />
<br/>
    </li>
</ul>

<br/>
<br/>
<span data-bind="text: fullVol "></span>
```

Javascript:

```
    function Part (data) {

       var self = this;
        self.Vol= ko.observable(data.Vol);

    }


    function AppViewModel() {
       var self = this;


        self.Parts = ko.observableArray([new Part({"Vol": 1}), new Part({"Vol":2}), new Part({"Vol":3})]);
        self.fullVol = ko.computed(function() {
            var total = 0;
           $.each(self.Parts(), function() { total += (this.Vol() ) })
            return total;
        });
    }


ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Here is my JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jwinstonaspen/Zmkew/6/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the `value: Vol` binding knockout won't convert your input to integer just stores the user entered data as a string.

So you need to parse it to integer before calculating the total:

```
$.each(self.Parts(), function() { total += (parseInt(this.Vol()) ) })
```

A fixed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/Zmkew/9/).

Now because you are doing the parsing you should not forget to deal with when case the user enters a non numeric input.

However you can easily write an [custom binding handler](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html) which abstracts away the parsing.

Or you can do with using `ko.extenders`. The documentation has an example as well [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html).